# Using apostrophe for plural with names

Tags: grammatical-number, apostrophe, names

Let's say the phrase I want to write is "all of the Mike Tysons, Donald Trumps, and Morpheus's in the world." I'm guessing that the first two names do not need one and the third does. Is this correct?

Answer (score 4):

One never forms plurals out of English words via an apostrophe. The apostrophe indicates a possessive, not a plural.

The English plural of *Morpheus* is simply the regular plural *Morpheuses*.

Comment: Well, *hardly* ever. When I was young the standard way (as in stylesheet and school standard) of pluralizing letters, numbers, initializations and a handful of things like *do's* was with *'s*. That's now mostly deprecated (and I'm glad to see it go, though *Dos and Don'ts* still looks odd to me), but it still lingers here and there.

Comment: @StoneyB That's why I said *words* :).

Answer (score 1):

What you are using is one form of posessive, like "Mike's shoes", or "Morpheus' eyeballs".

Instead you need a plural. Some words don't have a plural.
Some have an awkward plural, that comes from the originating language, like "Ox -> Oxen".

The plural of Morpheus is Morpheuses, I'd say. And yes, it's an awkward plural.